# Why is a PC browser reading HTML/CSS pages differently than an iPad?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a residential customer survey. I created a webpage using HTML/CSS and previewed the process on Chrome with the iPad view turned on.

This is my Chrome screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5k7i.jpg

This is my iPad screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IovUG.jpg

This is my code:

```
 <div class="slider-form"> 
          <h2 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5%; ">Overall 
 Satisfaction Rating</h2>
          <br> 
          <p style="float:left; margin-left: 20px; padding-right: 70px; 
 padding-top: 29px; 
          font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px;"> Your unit/home? </p>

          <div id="rs1" style="overflow: hidden;" class="rating_scale">

            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="unit" value="1" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/1.png"></span>
            </label>
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="unit" value="2" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/2.png"></span>
            </label>
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="unit" value="3" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/3.png"></span>
            </label>
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="unit" value="4" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/4.png"></span>
            </label>
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="unit" value="5" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/5.png"></span>
            </label>
          </div>

          <p style="float:left; margin-left: 20px; padding-top: 29px; 
          font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px;"> Your property/building? 
 </p>

          <div id="rs1" style="overflow: hidden;" class="rating_scale">
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="building" value="1" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/1.png"></span>
            </label>
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="building" value="2" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/2.png"></span>
            </label>
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="building" value="3" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/3.png"></span>
            </label>
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="building" value="4" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/4.png"></span>
            </label>
            <label >
              <input type="radio" name="building" value="5" /><span><img 
 class="smiley" src="img/5.png"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
```

Comment: Probably you have to use also media queries to style you website for different viewport

Comment: You need to make the width dynamic. Check https://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] including the relevant css code. Without that, it is impossible to tell what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's because browsers doesn't use the same rendering engine : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

There is great chance that Chrome and ios doesn't have the same default rendering on element.

You can try to reset it : https://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using a **flex** method. I put all of my left paragraphs and right radio inputs into a one div container. And assigned a class and id to them. The rest of it is just **CSS** **flex** method.

```
.container{
 display: flex;
 }
 .left {
 flex: 2;
 text-align: left;
 }
 .right{
 flex: 1;
 }
```

Thank you guys for quick answers.